# GarbageCollector stoped running after setting XX:MaxMetaspaceSize to the same old XX:MaxPermSize value

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot, permgen

During a migration of a Java application from Java 6 + Jboss to Java 8 + Tomcat.

We replaced the old `XX:MaxPermSize` value by setting a value for the `XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` in the new Java 8 version.

The Garbage Collector stoped running after some hours, something is missing, sould i set a value for the `XX:MetaspaceSize` value or other params ?

The application is based on Spring MVC with a lot of JSP, and we never had memory problem like swapping on disk ... when we were on JBOSS + Java 6.

Comment: How did you know that "Garbage Collector stopped running"? What is the expected behavior vs. the actual behavior?

Comment: Have enabled flags to get the garbage collector log file? Have you enabled a heap dump in case of out of memory? Here you have some useful flags. Kindly attach the garbage collector log file or any error message      XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -Xloggc:/some/path/yourserver/gclog.txt

Comment: Setting the `MaxMetaspaceSize`option to the same value as the `MaxPermSize` option of older JVMs makes no sense. Metaspace and PermGen are entirely different things. Even potential reasons to set these options are different. Setting the `MaxPermSize` was used to make a fixed size thing larger, setting `MaxMetaspaceSize` is used to restrict an otherwise unlimited thing.

Comment: @apangin The server CPU were all fully used, and in AppDynamics ( monitoring tool ) i have seen that the curve in GC was high and the GC didn't work to reduce it.

Comment: @Holger when we don't put the MaxMetaSpaceSize flag the application begin swapping memory on disk, but when putting it the RAM become available but the GC stopped cleaning objects we can see i high curve in the GC graph then server begin saturating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that's we discover a memory leak that wasn't obvious on Java 6.

On java 8 there more elements in Metaspace and if the garbage collector is not able de collect them the Metaspace grow until Swapping the Disk memory.